# Fade In With data on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fadein, fadeout

I want to show my **post->id** with *fade in*, I was try to search but I can't find it. Please Help me!!!

---

---

---

*forgive me if I have bad language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angularjs, You wanna start working with basic animation stuff, you can know the [Animation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

Basic fade out Example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button ng-click="hideStuff()">Click me!</button>
<div class="default" ng-hide="hidden" ng-class="{fade: 
    startFade}">This will get hidden!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.default{
    opacity: 1;
}

 .fade{
      -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
       transition: opacity 2s;
       opacity: 0;
 }
```

Angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.hideStuff = function () {
        $scope.startFade = true;
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.hidden = true;
        }, 2000);

    };

});
```